# How to properly convert a list[str] into a list[int]?

Tags: python, flask, type-conversion

I have this route in flask that receive a `data` from the client side(Angular). I am getting the data with the use of `data = request.data.decode("UTF-8")` the result will be this one: `"[1,2,3,4,5]"`. In order for me to remove these `"[]"`, I used `data1 = data.strip("[]")`, the result will be this one `"1,2,3,4,5"`. In order for me to make it a `list[str]` I used this one `data2 = [data1]`, the output will be now ["1,2,3,4,5"]. Lastly, in order for me to convert it in a `list[int]`, I used this one `finalData = list(map(int,data2[0].split(",")))`, which will result in this one [1,2,3,4,5].

**The Problem:**
But everytime I used this code flask always prompt this error :

File "C:\Users\bagal\Desktop\hello_flask\dummyLogin.py", line 69, in reportData

finalData = list(map(int,data2[0].split(",")))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

**The Code:**

```
 @app.route("/adminData", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
    def reportData():
         data = request.data.decode("UTF-8")
         data1 = data.strip("[]")
         data2 = [data1]
        finalData = list(map(int,data2[0].split(",")))
```

**Note:** I am using the fetched data in machine learning model, and sorry for a long explanation at the top, hope someone will help.

Comment: `finalData = json.loads(data)`

Comment: this prompt sir json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: `json.loads("[1,2,3,4,5]")` returns the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, not sure what your data variable is but based on your question and what you said the variable is equal to it should work

Comment: it works now sir, thanks, but is there a way I can ignore this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''?

Comment: This is JSON. Use the `json` library. You aren't working with a `list[str]` at all. It's just a string. But don't manually try to convert it into a list. Use `json`... because it is a JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire string looks to be a valid python expression containing only literals. You could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to process the entire string at once.

```py
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3,4,5]")
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: this prompt the error sir, File "<unknown>", line 0
    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it works now sir, thanks, but is there a way I can ignore this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''?

Comment: Almost certainly, the OP should be using `json`, not `eval`.